# Proper way to search for contacts Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, search, contacts, cncontact

I'm making an Apple Messages app clone and am currently mimicking "New Message" design. I have a `UITableView` (to display the results) with a `UISearchController` (to search for contacts).

**I'm trying to find the best way to search through a user's contacts on their phone while their typing.**

The function `CNContact.predicateForContacts` allows me to search for contacts by either a name, phone number, or email address. But, I'm unsure if this is an efficient method because the search needs to be like the Messages app; where a user starts typing typing it searches for multiple matching fields and displays those results almost instantly. For example, if a user types in a letter, it will search for matching names and email addresses or if they type in a number it will search for matching names, phone numbers, and emails with.

*What is the best practice to do this??* I looked at everywhere and even watch Apple's WWDC 15 video on contacts to find the best way for this but have not found a concrete explanation / answer.

Comment: I wonder why you cannot/aren't use `CNContactPickerDelegate` to search the default contact list. 

Comment: I want to keep the same look as Apple's Messages where the user can type in what they're searching and have a table automatically update the results instead of just showing the generic contacts app page.

Comment: @fphelp have you found any solutions . let me know i am facing same thing